# jQuery Cycle 2: Load link value of active slide

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using jQuery Cycle 2 plugin to switch years in a menu on this page http://webees.site/zufanek-cz/kronika/. Once you click the selected year, it loads a new query of WordPress posts with AJAX Load More solution (https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/). I'd like to do this automatically. Set some timer (lets say to 1 second) and activate link automatically after that time.

However I'm not sure how to do this, jQuery Cycle 2 has a cycle-after event but I wasn't able to get it working with timer.

```
<span class="switch restore">
    <a href="#" class="restore" data-posts-per-page="4" data-year="" data-month="" data-pause="false" data-pause-override="false" data-preloaded="false">obnovit</a> <!-- this is used to restore a default query -->
</span>
<div class="carousel">
    <a href="#" class="prev">Předchozí</a> <!-- shows previous year -->
    <a href="#" class="next">Další</a> <!-- shows next year -->
    <ul class="nav-years cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx="carousel" data-cycle-slides='> li.year' data-cycle-timeout="0" data-cycle-prev=".prev" data-cycle-next=".next" data-cycle-carousel-visible="1" data-allow-wrap="false" data-cycle-carousel-vertical="true"><!-- initializes slideshow -->
        <li class="year year-1" id="year-1"><span class="switch"><a href="#" data-year="2016" data-posts-per-page="1000" data-month="" data-pause="false" data-pause-override="false" data-preloaded="false">2016</span></a></li> <!-- one particular year with a new query, this should be loaded automatically second after being displayed --> 
        <li class="year year-2" id="year-2"><span class="switch"><a href="#" data-year="2015" data-posts-per-page="1000" data-month="" data-pause="false" data-pause-override="false" data-preloaded="false">2015</span></a></li>
        <li class="year year-3" id="year-3"><span class="switch"><a href="#" data-year="2014" data-posts-per-page="1000" data-month="" data-pause="false" data-pause-override="false" data-preloaded="false">2014</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```